# SharePoint 2013 Internet Explorer CheckOut problems - Error message

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, check-out, internet-explorer, check-in, windows10

We have problems when open a document in a Document Library with Document Version History and/or CheckOut required in Internet Explorer 11.
When opening the document we don't get the question to CheckOut, only EditWorkbook or Edit Document. After choosing that we get error message

"https://xxxxx.xxx.com/sites/sitename/filename.xlsx is not checked out"

We are not user but it seams to have happend after installing Window10 Security Patches for March 2019
We are in the middle of update all our clients with the new patches when we discoverd this so we are very anxious to here if anyone else have this kind of problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best to test is to remove the patch and see does the issue persists.  If it does open the ticket with Microsoft it was caused by security patch it is a free ticket.